# spring-boot-2.0.6 freemarker mvc View print request model values twice

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, view, freemarker

I am using freemarker view with spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE,
But my ftl view print request model value twice in HTML like "${errorTitle}" -> "PG ErrorPGError" .
If anybody has a solution, please let me know the way.
I am struggling with these problems for 3 days.

```
    [freemarker configuration bean]

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig()throws IOException, TemplateException {

        final FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/WEB-INF/view/");
        Properties settings = new Properties(); 
        settings.setProperty(
   freemarker.template.Configuration.TEMPLATE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_KEY, "rethrow");
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }


    [/paygate/error.ftl]
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Error Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>${errorTitle}</h1>
    <p>${errorMessage}</p>

    </body>
    </html>

    [pom.xml]
        :::
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        :::

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    @CrossOrigin
    @SkipSessionCheck
    @GetMapping("/error)
    public ModelAndView errorView(@RequestParam("errorMessage") String errorMessage) throws ResultCodeException {

        logger.error(AppUtil.excetionToString(e)) ;
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.addObject("errorTitle", "PG Error") ;
        model.addObject("errorMessage", errorMessage) ;
        model.setViewName("paygate/error");
        return model ;       
    }
```

Comment: Quite bizarre. What does  `${'test'}` do? Does that also print `testtest`?

Comment: @ddekany Yes, It's awesome. I don't know why...

Comment: The server sends the data as twice when using curl cmd test.  PG ?? ?? ???PG ?? ?? ???
Freemarker Test...Freemarker Test...

Comment: So it sends the *whole* template output twice, right? You should probably check the code the invokes FreeMarker.